# What is the best way to pass data from a Windows hook to another process?

Tags: winapi, rust, hook, ipc

I have implemented a Windows keyboard hook in Rust and would like to pass the data it reads to another process that can actually make use of the data. I tried creating a named pipe and having the callback function write the data to the pipe, but I've found there is a significant amount of overhead in that method. What methods would you suggest for passing data from keyboard hooks to another process?

Comment: Write a driver.

Comment: Why can't the other process create a keyboard hook as well? Are you preventing the message from propagating?

Comment: In IPC, Share memory is usually faster than pipes.

Comment: Here is a good article related to memory mapped files --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the suggestions. I implemented the mapped memory approach and found that was significantly faster than named pipes, but also more complicated from my perspective. I actually ended up falling back on the Windows messaging system and passed everything using PostMessageW, which was very simple and fast enough. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Of course, you can mark yourself if this method is suitable for you and may help the people later.